# Border around the image selected when radio button visibility Hidden

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This is the code from the WordPress backend(Meta) →

```
 <div class="cmb-td">
    <ul class="cmb2-radio-list cmb2-list">  
        <li><input type="radio" class="cmb2-option" name="_yourprefix_demo_radio_images" id="_yourprefix_demo_radio_images1" value="img1"> <label for="_yourprefix_demo_radio_images1"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/E8117F/ffffff?text=Image%201" alt="Image 1" title="Image 1"></label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" class="cmb2-option" name="_yourprefix_demo_radio_images" id="_yourprefix_demo_radio_images2" value="img2"> <label for="_yourprefix_demo_radio_images2"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/f9a82f/ffffff?text=Image%202" alt="Image 2" title="Image 2"></label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" class="cmb2-option" name="_yourprefix_demo_radio_images" id="_yourprefix_demo_radio_images3" value="img3"> <label for="_yourprefix_demo_radio_images3"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/49aed7/ffffff?text=Image%203" alt="Image 3" title="Image 3"></label></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="cmb2-metabox-description">Use images for the radio button labels</p>
```

This is actually coming from the core of Wordpress so we have little scope to change the actual HTML.

```
.cmb2-option: checked {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

I am doing above to hide the radio button as I want to make selection appear as if coming from the image selected, but How can I create a border around the image selected?
[image]

Comment: Can you make the codpen or jsfiddle so that we can review and solve it in the mean time you can give the border for img or for li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF JS is allowed, then with the help of little JS and CSS, provided there is a restriction in the html structure, you can achive it.

CSS:

```
 .cmb2-option:checked ~ label {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .cmb2-list {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .cmb2-list input {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999px;
  }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".cmb2-radio-list", function() {
    $(this).find("input").trigger('click');
  });
});
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: can you guide me A-Z; I mean fromm Hiding radio buttons to the image border?

Comment: HTML cant be altered even slightly(coming from WP). can you make it work exactly with the actual HTML/classes posted?

Comment: I clearly posted this in my question →This is actually coming from the core of Wordpress so we have little scope to change the actual HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sibling selector to achieve that:

```
.cmb2-option:checked ~ label {
   border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors